# How to get the arguments binded into boost::function?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-function

From the boost::bind docs( http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_functions ), "The arguments that bind takes are copied and held internally by the returned function object", but if there's a way I could get the arguments copied in those function object?

i.e.:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void doSomthing(std::string str)
{
}

int main()
{    
    boost::function<void(void)> func_obj = boost::bind(&doSomthing, "some string");
    //how can I get the std::string argument("some string") through func_obj?
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean you want to read them out of your func_objc variable? not really possible.

Comment: yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: We have boost 1. **53** now, not 1.35.

Comment: sorry, just fix that, but not really matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really much you can do with a Boost.Function object, except call it - and that's by design.  (You can copy it, destroy it, compare to NULL, but not much more).

Consider the following code:

```
void Foo () {}
void Bar ( int i ) { printf ( "%d", i ); }

boost::function<void(void)> fFoo (Foo);
boost::function<void(void)> fBar = boost::bind (Bar, 23);
```

These two objects are designed to be treated identically. They are the same type, and behave the same. There's no mechanism in boost function for distinguishing between them.

For a great description of the techniques used in Boost.Function (and other places), check out Nevin Liber's [type erasure talk from Boostcon 2010](http://blip.tv/boostcon/nevin-liber-type-erasure-3989198)